# AngularJS bootstrap dropdown not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I have a drop-down of AngularJS Bootstrap which displays two options. It works completely fine in FF and Chrome but IE shows a weird behavior. The drop-down doesn't show the options and seem to be hidden. After resizing the window, the options are shown just like a dropdown works.

Angular version is used is 1.4.3

Here's my code

```
 <div class="btn-group ViewEditOption" dropdown>
                        <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="width: 100px; font-size: 14px; color: #364395;"
                            dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
                            Can {{user.projectRoleName}} <span class="caret" style="margin-left: 5%;"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
                            <li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="role in availableRoles"><a class="dd" href="#" ng-click="updateRole($event, user, role)">
                                Can {{role.name}}</a></li>
                    </div>
```

Comment: You're not closing the </ul> on your example code, your application is not closing it too?

Comment: i added the <./ul> in the end but that didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a actually a problem with Bootstrap version 3.3.5. There's an incompatibility on certain versions of IE on Windows 8.
You can downgrade to version 3.1.1. It'll work fine

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks. Changed the version of bootstrap to 3.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is with some other section of the code. I have created a sample of `Ui-Bootstrap Dropdown`.

**Html**

```
<div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">
    <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
      <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
        Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
        <li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="item in items">
          <a href="#" ng-click="updateRole($event,item)">{{item}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Angular**

```
var app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('DropdownCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    'The first choice!',
    'And another choice for you.',
    'but wait! A third!'
  ];

  $scope.updateRole =function(event,item){
      console.log(event.target);
      console.log(item);
  }

});
```

Please refer this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QfSfz3rzwuNYlO3QjRgD?p=preview).

I have tested this code on **IE-9 and IE-11** and this code is working.

Comment: The plunker you gave worked fine on my IE because the CDN you used of  bootstrap was 3.1.1. t